# Dealing with enormous datasets with Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have a general question about Impala vs some traditional SQL database systems. I've heard that Impala can take certain SQL statements quite literally and spit out tables with billions of rows (such as what might happen with a join statement with duplicate rows). As a narrower example suppose I run something like "SELECT * FROM database" . As far as immediate console output is concerned, I understand that most traditional SQL databases will stop running when a limit of say, 1000 entries is reached. Is the same true of Impala? In other words, if I run "SELECT * FROM database" in Impala, is it in theory doing more work, even though it will ultimately spit out a limited number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends what you use to do the query. If you just run from the command line in Bash or the Impala shell it will fetch all the results, however if you use Hue, it will page through the results like you describe. Actually the same is true for any database, if you're using a GUI to access it, you can run something like an export to csv command to get the full result set, or if you're accessing programatically, you would use `fetchall()`.